# Upload clickonce to SharePoint

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-server

I'm following this [tutorial](http://blog.karstein-consulting.com/2011/08/16/walkthrough-deploy-clickonce-application-as-sharepoint-2010-solution-package/) to upload a clickonce application to SharePoint. This is my Elements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="MyClickonce" Path="MyClickonce20110815152200">
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\AvalonDock.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/AvalonDock.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\AvalonDock.Themes.Aero.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/AvalonDock.Themes.Aero.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\Catel.MVVM.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/Catel.MVVM.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\IntelliSense.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/IntelliSense.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\Microsoft.Visualstudio.Activities.HostView.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/Microsoft.Visualstudio.Activities.HostView.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\Microsoft.Windows.Design.Extensibility.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/Microsoft.Windows.Design.Extensibility.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\Microsoft.Windows.Shell.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/Microsoft.Windows.Shell.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\PATOneRule_Builder.application" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/PATOneRule_Builder.application" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\PATOneRule_Builder.exe.config.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/PATOneRule_Builder.exe.config.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\PATOneRule_Builder.exe.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/PATOneRule_Builder.exe.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\PATOneRule_Builder.exe.manifest" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/PATOneRule_Builder.exe.manifest" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\RibbonControlsLibrary.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/RibbonControlsLibrary.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\rule.ico.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/rule.ico.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\RulesDll.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/RulesDll.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\RunWorkflow.exe.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/RunWorkflow.exe.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\de\Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/de/Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\de\Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/de/Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\de\System.Spatial.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/de/System.Spatial.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\en\Microsoft.IdentityModel.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/en/Microsoft.IdentityModel.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\es\Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/es/Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\es\Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/es/Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\es\System.Spatial.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/es/System.Spatial.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\fr\Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/fr/Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\fr\Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/fr/Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\fr\System.Spatial.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/fr/System.Spatial.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\it\Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/it/Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\it\Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/it/Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\it\System.Spatial.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/it/System.Spatial.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\ja\Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/ja/Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\ja\Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/ja/Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\ja\System.Spatial.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/ja/System.Spatial.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\ko\Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/ko/Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\ko\Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/ko/Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\ko\System.Spatial.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/ko/System.Spatial.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\ru\Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/ru/Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\ru\Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/ru/Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\ru\System.Spatial.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/ru/System.Spatial.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\WorkflowTemplate\EmptyWorkflow.xaml.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/WorkflowTemplate/EmptyWorkflow.xaml.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\WorkflowTemplate\SchemaCountryConcentration.xaml.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/WorkflowTemplate/SchemaCountryConcentration.xaml.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\WorkflowTemplate\SchemaCurrencyConcentration.xaml.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/WorkflowTemplate/SchemaCurrencyConcentration.xaml.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\WorkflowTemplate\SchemaIssuerConcentration.xaml.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/WorkflowTemplate/SchemaIssuerConcentration.xaml.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\zh-Hans\Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/zh-Hans/Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\zh-Hans\Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/zh-Hans/Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\zh-Hans\System.Spatial.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/zh-Hans/System.Spatial.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\zh-Hant\Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/zh-Hant/Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\zh-Hant\Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/zh-Hant/Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\zh-Hant\System.Spatial.resources.dll.deploy" Url="Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/zh-Hant/System.Spatial.resources.dll.deploy" />
   <File Path="MyClickonce\PATOneRule_Builder.application" Url="PATOneRule_Builder.application" />
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

I think that the error is in the first line:

```
 <Module Name="MyClickonce" Path="MyClickonce20110815152200">
```

Because when i delete attribute path i can do the deployment. Do Anyone know what can be the reason?

ERROR when deploy:

```
 Error  68  Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Failed to instantiate file "Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/AvalonDock.dll.deploy" from module "MyClickonce": Source path "Features\MyClickonceDeployment_Feature1\MyClickonce20110815152200\MyClickonce\Application Files\PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271\AvalonDock.dll.deploy" not found.
    0   0   MyClickonceDeployment
```

PD: If I deploy the solution without path attribute, when I try to open the clickonce application i get the following error message:

```
ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [3/18/2013 12:53:10 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
    - Downloading http://ofe-11/Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/Application Files/PATOneRule_Builder_1_0_0_271/PATOneRule_Builder.exe.manifest did not succeed.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
    --- Inner Exception ---
    System.Net.WebException
    - The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
    - Source: System
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
No transaction information is available.
```

Comment: Environment: Microsoft server 2008, sharepoint 2013, visual studio 2012

Comment: Are you deploying this as an app?

Comment: How can i do this? I'm deploying with the normal mode

Comment: When you set-up your project in VS you can select App for SharePoint 2013